# How do I create a looping random array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, random

Im trying to create an array with 100 random values from 1 to 1000, and multiply each by 4

so far I have:

```
$numbers = array(rand(1, 1000),rand(1, 1000),rand(1, 1000),
    rand(1, 1000),rand(1, 1000),rand(1, 1000)

for($x=0; $x<100; $x++)
    echo $numbers[$x]*4 . "<br/>";
```

How do I get rand(1,1000) to repeat 100 times without copy pasting? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$numbers = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
    $numbers[] = rand(1, 1000);

foreach ($numbers as $number)
    echo ($number * 4) . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this or I misunderstood your question:

```
$randArray=array();
for($x=0;$x<100,$x++)
{
    $randArray[]=rand(1,1000)*4;

    //echo $randArray[$x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 100; $x++) {
    $numbers[] = rand(1,1000) * 4 . "<br>";
}
```

You could of course loop *again* if you need to have the values without them being multiplied by 4 for some reason.

Another possible solution without the inelegant loop:

```
array_map(function () { return rand(1,1000); }, range(1,1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$numbers = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++)
{
    $numbers[] = rand(1, 1000);
    echo $numbers[$i] * 4 . "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```